# How to show the following two integrals are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

A physics paper that I am reading claims that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{\infty} d p \frac{J_0(p) \cos (p \Lambda)}{\cosh \left(\frac{u}{4} p\right)}=\frac{1}{2 \pi u} \int_{-\pi}^\pi d k \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{2 \pi}{u}(\Lambda-\sin k)\right)
\end{equation}

where $J_0(p)$ is the Bessel J function.

Any hints on how to show these two integrals are the same?

Comment: I would guess it's replacing $J_0$ with an integral form, then swapping order of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bessel $J_0$ can be expressed in integral form as
$$
J_0(p) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\cos(p\sin k)dk.
$$
Putting this into the integral on the LHS gives
$$
\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(p\sin k)\cos(p\Lambda)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{pu}{4}\right)dpdk,
$$
where we have used the evenness of the integrand to extend the $p$ integral to the whole real line. This will be useful later.

Next we use the product-to-sum identity $2\cos(p\sin k)\cos(p \Lambda) = \cos[(\Lambda + \sin k)p]+\cos[(\Lambda -\sin k)p]$ to get
$$
\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\left[\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos([\Lambda + \sin k]p)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{pu}{4}\right)dpdk+\int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty\cos([\Lambda -\sin k]p)\operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{pu}{4}\right)dpdk\right].
$$
Now apply the substitution $k\rightarrow -k$ to the first integral and $p = 4q/u$ to both integrals to get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi^2u}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \cos\left(4\frac{\Lambda -\sin k}{u}q\right) \operatorname{sech}q\,dq dk = \frac{1}{2\pi^2 u}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \mathcal{F}[\operatorname{sech}]\left(\frac{4}{u}[\Lambda-\sin k]\right) dk
$$
where $\mathcal{F}[\operatorname{sech}]$ is the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sech}$. This can be found in a Fourier transform table as $\mathcal{F}[\operatorname{sech}](x) = \pi \operatorname{sech}(\pi x/2)$. Using this in the integral above gives
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi u}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \operatorname{sech}\left(\frac{2\pi}{u}\left[\Lambda-\sin k\right]\right)dk,
$$
the RHS of the original equation.